# textarea not receiving descendant CSS property

Tags: css, xhtml, textarea, background-color

I have the CSS setting:

> .missing textarea {background-color: #fffcc !important;}

And the html looks like so:

> `<div id="label-add" class="jscript xtra-box sub-question missing">`
>      `<p>Additional Health Care Instructions</p>`
>      `<textarea id="addrule" name="addrule"></textarea>`
>      `</div>`

It uses the XHTML 1.0 transitional DOCTYPE.
And, I've tried in FF and Chrome, and I'm not getting the textarea's background-color; it's not even showing up as overwritten in the debug console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color is missing a char. "#fffcc" needs one more char.

Comment: Thank you~! >.> stupid mistake

Answer (score 1):

Your hex colour definition has only five digits. Can you try a full one with six?

Everything else looks in order to me.

Answer (score 1):

#fffcc is missing one character